# Recompiling files with "webpack watch" doesn't work for minor changes

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint

I use the JavaScript Standard Style with Eslint in my project. 
In my Eslint configuration semilicon are not allowed.
If my code look like this :

```
console.log('hey bro !');
```

The console return an error "extra semicolon".
Now if I try to remove the semilicon, Webpack doesn't compiling the file and I can't see if the error is fixed or not.

How to force Webpack to compile files each time even when they are minor changes.

Comment: My code ? If you use webpack try to add and remove a semicolon or a blank space, and you will see. Webpack doesn't compile the new change.

Comment: Your missing semicolon may be elsewhere in the code, so we need to see as much as possible.

Comment: I think you don't understand the problem. Read my first post again.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the latest webpack version; found a corresponding [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1272) which has now been reopened.